# Emploi de « à la » pour signifier « comme »

Tags: usage, locutions, ellipse

> Un raisonnement **à la** Cauchy donne lieu à l'introduction du tenseur des couples de contraintes.

Peut-on employer **à la** pour désigner comme (i.e. comme celui de Cauchy) ?
Si oui, dans quel registre ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

en général

> à la

est une manière courte de dire

> à la façon/manière de

à mon avis, il convient de l'utiliser dans un registre familier/courant (je ne l'utiliserais pas en registre soutenu)

On peut aussi l'utiliser dans des phrases comme

> J'ai fais ça *à la va-vite*

pour dire

> J'ai fais ça sans trop détailler / c'est un premier jet

Comment: Il n'y a pas d'ellipse dans « à la louche », c'est une autre expression.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Bonne remarque, j'ai supprimé cette partie de ma réponse du coup :)

Comment: Je pense que *à la* pour *la manière de* est plutôt familier avec un nom d'une personne, et peut même avoir une connotation négative, impliquant un manque d'originalité ou une allusion à des manières vues négativement (*un roman à la Balzac* vs. *un roman écrit à la manière de Balzac*, *un discours à la Trump* vs. *un discours à la manière de Trump*). Mais avec un adjectif de nationalité, je ne vois pas de différence de niveau de langage, ni de connotation particulière: exemple *la cuisine à la française, un show à l'américaine*.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de la musique et des compositeurs, *à la* (à mon opinion en inspiration directe du *alla* italien) est tout aussi soutenu que respectueux.